# Submit passed ViewModel value, if there is no Field in the Form for it

Tags: forms, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form with a ViewModel and several (maybe prefilled) fields. One of the fields, a checkbox, is only accessable by the admin and not present for normal users. I create my fields with `@Html.TextboxFor(...)`.

When a normal user submits the form all data will be passed correctly, but the value for the admin-field in the Model has the default value (false). If the value was true before the action, the value will be changed,but the user shouldn't be able to do this.

**How can I submit the value from the given ViewModel, which the Controller sends to the View for prefilling, if there is no Checkbox?**

*Note: 
  I don't want to create two forms for normal users and admins.
A hidden field for the checkbox value also can be changed by the user.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code, it's difficult to say exactly where your problem lies, but in general, if you're handling the post data properly, you won't have any issues.

You mention a view model, but if you are in fact using a view model, it's unclear why you're having problems. If you don't want the boolean reset by the post data, then simply don't map that property over to your entity class. If you're using some sort of automatic mapping that does this, then you should set that property to be ignored, so that it's not included.

Additionally, you should make sure you're starting with the *existing* entity, pulled fresh from the database, which would in this case have the boolean set to true. Then, when you map over the values from your view model (excluding this boolean property), it will remain true. If you're creating some new instance based on the view model, there's no way to know it was initially true.